# Could not conect to socket server after some time of working

Tags: java, sockets, connection

I wrote Java server for my multiplayer Android game. Communication between server and game goes through sockets. **After some time of server running users can not connect to server.**

The problem is not a performance issue, because of cpu usage lower than 10% and this is not related to internet connection speed.

So I think that the problem may be caused by some limits for active connections to server on OS level or router, but I don't know if that is the problem...

Please, help me to figure out root cause of the problem and sorry for my English.

Comment: How long of a connection do you get until it disconnects? Also, what does "I wrote a Java server mean?" Can you clarify that, maybe explain it more? Also, can you show the exact error your seeing and what code you think is causing it?

Comment: Define 'cannot connect'.